# Linq average working hours between login and logout

Tags: .net, linq

I am working on Linq query. Basically I am trying to find average daily working hours between login and logout.

The catch is, user can login and logout multiple times each day or can login on one day and logout in a later day,

I am just in the middle of query making so far I have something like this

```
    MinutesLoggedIn=(w.logoutdatetime.Value-w.logindatetime.Value).Minutes,
                            startDate=w.logindatetime,
             thatDayWorked = 1440 - (w.logoutdatetime.Value - w.logindatetime.Value).Minutes > 0 ? 1440 - w.logindatetime.Value.Minute : w.logoutdatetime.Value.Minute - w.logindatetime.Value.Minute             

             });
```

I am able to find difference between login logout but without following the required assumptions. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: how is it EF or LINQ related?
I assume you only use `DateTime` objects by the code you provided

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you have something similar to this data structure

```
public class SessionObj
{
    public DateTime LogInDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogOutDate { get; set; }
}
```

If you have list of these objects you can get minutes for each session and then calculate average by the use of `Average` function

```
var averageTimeForSession = new List<SessionObj>()
    .Select(x => (x.LogOutDate - x.LogInDate).Minutes)
    .Average();

var averageTimeForSessionPerDate = new List<SessionObj>()
    .GroupBy(x => x.LogInDate)
    .Select(x => x.Sum(y => (y.LogOutDate - y.LogInDate).Minutes))
    .Average();
```